# Fullcalendar resizing not fullday events

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm adapting the fullcalendar with time and hours. As the `nextDayThreshold` is exclusive, I'm substracting one day when selecting days in calendar and adding the end dates in '23:56:56' format.

The problem is that I can't resize events without having `allDay: true` are there any method for doing that in month view? Any better method to avoid the wrong range that fullcalendar show on render and select (yes I know that in doc expecifies that is exclusive, and its the defined behaviour, but is a wrong way to show that. If I select the days 1 to 5, in human perspective it does not have sense to show from 1 to another number different than 5) (I spent many days reading about that is for implement it like google calendar, but when I use google calendar it works different selecing or rendering the correct range from 1 to 5).

here is the code (fullcalendar v4):

```
var calendar;
var startDateSelected;  //YYY-MM-DD
var endDateSelected;    //YYY-MM-DD
var evTittleSelected;
var typeFilterArray = [];
var userFilter = '';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    drawCalendar();
});


function drawCalendar() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    if(calendar != undefined) calendar.destroy();
    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list'],
        locale: 'es',
        selectable: true,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        columnFormat: { 
            month: 'ddd', 
            week: 'ddd d/M', 
            day: 'dddd d/M' 
        },
        header: {
            left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear,today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
        },
        events: [{
            daysOfWeek: [0,6],
            rendering:"background",
            color: "#ff9f89",
            overLap: false,
            allDay: true
        }],
        events: [
            {
                id: '1',
                title: 'title 1',
                start: '2019-08-05 00:00:00',
                end: '2019-08-08 23:59:59'
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                title: 'title 2',
                start: '2019-08-12 12:00:00',
                end: '2019-08-12 12:30:30'
            },
            {
                id: '3',
                title: 'title 3',
                start: '2019-08-19 08:00:30',
                end: '2019-08-22 12:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: '4',
                title: 'title 4',
                start: '2019-08-19 08:05:30',
                end: '2019-08-22 23:59:59'
            },
        ],


select: function (info) {
        startDateSelected = moment(info.startStr).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        endDateSelected = moment(info.endStr).subtract(1, 'days')
            .format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        if(endDateSelected.substr(11) == '00:00:00') {
            endDateSelected = endDateSelected.substr(0,11) + '23:59:59';
        }
        console.log(startDateSelected + ' ' + endDateSelected);
    },
    eventClick: function(info) { 
        evTittleSelected = info.event.title;
        startDateSelected =  moment(info.event.start).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        endDateSelected =  moment(info.event.end).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        if(endDateSelected.substr(11) == '00:00:00') {
            endDateSelected = endDateSelected.substr(0,11) + '23:59:59';
        }
        console.log(startDateSelected + ' ' + endDateSelected);
    },
    eventResize: function(info) {
        evTittleSelected = info.event.title;
        startDateSelected =  moment(info.event.start).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        endDateSelected =  moment(info.event.end).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        console.log(startDateSelected + ' ' + endDateSelected);
    },
    eventDrop: function(info) {
        evTittleSelected = info.event.title;
        startDateSelected =  moment(info.event.start).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        endDateSelected =  moment(info.event.end).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        console.log(startDateSelected + ' ' + endDateSelected);
    }
});
calendar.render();
```

}

Comment: "are there any method for doing that in month view" ...short answer: no. Month view doesn't have a concept of time (it only deals with date), so if you are resizing an event which has time, then month view cannot handle it because it cannot know what time you want to change it to. Even if you're just using the time as a workaround for the exclusive end date feature, that is still true. I would consider implementing an alternative workaround where you increase the end date of your events by 1, whilst keeping all-day as true, and not using a fake time.

Comment: "is a wrong way to show that" ...that's a matter of opinion. There are good, logical reasons for making the end date behave in this way, but equally you have found a situation where it's not helpful. I think there are arguments both ways. Perhaps you could submit a feature request to fullCalendar to have an option where you can switch this behaviour on and off, to give people more flexibility.

Comment: P.S. _"If I select the days 1 to 5, in human perspective it does not have sense to show from 1 to another number different than 5_ ...it depends on how you see it. If you say that an event ends on `2019-08-07`, without specifying a time, then that is actually an ambiguous declaration. A day is not a single moment in time, it's a large quantity of time. So exactly when on that day should we treat the event as ending? We have to make some kind of assumption. The most logical basic assumption is to take it literally as ending at the _start_ of the specified day, i.e. at `00:00:00` (midnight)

Comment: If we assume that, then no part of the event occurs on that day (since the event ended at the moment the day began), and it's logical not to display it there. We have to make some kind of assumption about the time because we are not dealing only with "month" type views which do not care about time, fullCalendar also provides time-based views such as the timegrid, and for that we need to know exactly what part of the grid to fill in for each event. So you could change the rules to assume that a date without time means the _end_ of the specified day, but it would require changing the core code.

Comment: P.S. what you have heard about google calendar is correct in some respects - if you insert an event into google calendar using their API, specifying only a date (without a time) for the end, then it will behave as an exclusive end date, just like fullCalendar. I know this because I've implemented such a thing and came up against that behaviour. I worked around it by adding 1 day to the end date. I suggest you do the same here. Adding arbitrary times into the picture creates additional complications and undesirable effects, as you've discovered with the resizing problem.

Comment: Thanks for all of the details that will help me a lot. So ok I have to rething a bit  my case. Thanks